# How to update child window?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have already opened child window by following code

```
var myWindow = window.open('','','width=1250,height=1000,resizable=yes,fullscreen=yes');
var doc = myWindow.document;
doc.open();
doc.write(divText);
doc.close();
```

now I am trying to update the html of that already opened `myWindow`. How will I be able to do that?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to do `doc.open()` and `doc.close()`.

You can do the following:

```
var myWindow = window.open('','','width=1250,height=1000,resizable=yes,fullscreen=yes');
var doc = myWindow.document;
doc.body.innerHTML = divText;

// Then, when you want, change it:
doc.body.innerHTML = "Something else";
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

[**DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/yinubeyo/1/)

```
$("#sd").on("click",function(){
var myWindow = window.open('','','width=1250,height=1000,resizable=yes,fullscreen=yes').document.write("DDD");
});
```

use `document.write()` to add text on your newly created window.

Comment: This will only set a property called `innerHTML` on `myWindow`. It will not change the text inside of it.

Comment: Obviously, that's why I am telling your code is wrong. `Window` objects don't have `innerHTML` attribute, `Element` objects do. Try it by yourself: create the window and then write `myWindow.innerHTML` it will be `undefined` because `myWindow` has no `innerHTML` proeprty. If you do `myWindow.innerHTML = 'something'` you are only creating that property, not changing the text inside `myWindow`.